# Android, Shared Preferences basic In

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i'm having a little trouble saving at Android's SharedPreferences, it's really simple. I just want to have a click counter and save the numbers of clicks with SharedPrefs, here is the code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public int veces;
SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     prefs =  getSharedPreferences("MisPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

      veces = prefs.getInt("nroVeces", 0);
      //EditText TextOut = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Texty);
     // TextOut.setText("El boton ha sido tocado "+veces+"veces");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void Presionado(View view){
    EditText TextOut = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Texty);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    veces = prefs.getInt("NroVeces", 0);
    veces ++;
    TextOut.setText("El boton ha sido tocado "+veces+" veces.");
    editor.putInt("nroVeces", veces);
    editor.commit();


}
```

My counter (veces) freezes at 1, this is the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem, is that you name your counter different on reading and writing:

```
veces = prefs.getInt("NroVeces", 0);
// your code in between
editor.putInt("NroVeces", veces);
```

This should fix it.